# Using react-i18next as a translation provider for React Admin

Tags: react-admin

I am trying to use react-i18next as a translation provider for react-admin. React-admin provides documentation on how to setup a [custom translation provider](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Translation.html).

This was easy enough to follow and I created one for i18next:

```js
export const i18nProvider = {
    translate: (key, { _, smart_count, ...rest } = {}) => {
        return i18n.t(key, {
            defaultValue: _,
            count: smart_count,
            ...rest,
        });
    },
    changeLocale: (locale) => i18n.changeLanguage(locale),
    getLocale: () => i18n.language,
};
```

The problem I am having is that react-i18next uses suspense to load the translations, and this behavior does not seem to work when calling the `i18n.t` function directly like this, rather than through a [hook](https://react.i18next.com/latest/using-with-hooks):

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

function MyComponent() {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();

  return <h1>{t('Welcome to React')}</h1>
}

// i18n translations might still be loaded by the http backend
// use react's Suspense
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback="loading">
      <MyComponent />
    </Suspense>
  );
}
```

What ends up happening is that the i18n.t function is called before the translation is loaded, and ends up not showing the translations.

Is there a better approach to integrate react-i18next with react admin?

Comment: I don't know if you found a solution, but if I am not mistaken you can configure i18next to not use suspense. It will block until translations are loaded and then render the components. maybe that solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Instantiate i18n and simply import it when mounting your app

```js
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

import frTranslations from '~/locales/fr.json';

i18n
  // pass the i18n instance to react-i18next.
  .use(initReactI18next)
  // init i18next
  // for all options read: https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options
  .init({
    fallbackLng: 'fr',
    resources: {
      fr: { translation: frTranslations },
    },
  });

export default i18n;
```

```js
import App from './App';

import './i18n';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Then you can use it like you do

```js
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

function SearchFilter(props) {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read [react-i18n](https://react.i18next.com/getting-started#basic-sample) and [react-admin translation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Translation.html) to know the basics.

Make a json file from [react-admin available locales](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Translation.html#available-locales), choose one and locate the translation file. In my case the translation file is [index.js](https://github.com/areyliu6/ra-language-chinese-traditional/blob/master/index.js), the content is translated and stored in `public/locales/zh-tw/translation.json`. Make sure to include the `ra:` json key.

Step to walkthrough this solution:

1. `yarn add react-i18next@11.16.1 i18next@21.6.14`
2. In project dir `cd node_modules && ln -s ../public public` to import a translation file, e.g. `public/locales/zh-tw/translation.json`
3. Create `src/i18n.js` and add:

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import {initReactI18next} from "react-i18next";

import chineseTranslation from 'public/locales/zh-tw/translation.json';

// the translations
const resources = {
    "zh-TW": {
        translation: chineseTranslation
    }
};

i18n
    .use(initReactI18next) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
    .init({
        resources,
        lng: "zh-TW",

        // keySeparator: false, // we do not use keys in form messages.welcome

        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false // react already safes from xss
        }
    });

export default i18n;
```

4. In `src/index.js` add `import './i18n';`
5. In your `src/App.jsx`, apply the following:

```
import {Admin, Resource, ListGuesser} from "react-admin";
import * as React from "react";
import polyglotI18nProvider from 'ra-i18n-polyglot';
import chineseTranslation from 'public/locales/zh-tw/translation.json';

// @ts-ignore
const i18nProvider = polyglotI18nProvider((_) => chineseTranslation);

const LandingPage = () => (
    <Admin i18nProvider={i18nProvider}>
        <Resource name="users" list={ListGuesser}/>
    </Admin>
);

export default LandingPage;
```

I am using typescript for react-admin, so I added `//@ts-ignore` to get rid of compile error.

Comment: I just notice that `react-i18n` may not be needed, but one translation file to serve `react-i18n` and `react-admin i18nProvider` can surely make life easier.

Comment: He asked about how to use i18n with an http backend. You provide a solution with a static import.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use `i18t` features in `react-admin` outside of the component then you can do it without any problems:

```js
    // i18nProvider.ts - very basic example
    import polyglotI18nProvider from "ra-i18n-polyglot";
    import englishMessages from "../i18n/en";
    
    const i18nProvider = polyglotI18nProvider(locale => {
      if (locale === 'fr') {
        return import('../i18n/fr').then(messages => messages.default);
      }
      return englishMessages;
    }, 'en');
```

then just import the provider and use it even in utilities or providers:

```js
    import { i18nProvider } from "./i18nProvider";

    ...
    errText = i18nProvider.translate(
       "globalUsage.errors.user_is_disabled"
    );
```